# Writing a hundred records to files

Tags: php, file-writing, fputcsv

I want to write a hundred records continously in different files named with `time()`.

This code works well but writes only 1 record to each file. How can I do this?

```
$i=0;
$file= time();
foreach ($dizi as $fields) {
    $i++;
    if($i%100==0){
        $fp = fopen($file.'.csv', 'w');
    }
    fputcsv($fp, $fields,';','"');
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the entire code? what is `dizi` and how many elements do you have in it?  Why are you opening the file inside the if and closing it out? What does happen when the file is not open before you close it?

Comment: fflush($fp); Try adding this before fclose($fp);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your behavior is happening because you close the file after the first record and never open it again until arriving the 100th record.

I think the better approach to do what you want is open the first file outside the loop and if got to 100 records close and open new file.

Try something like this:

```
$i = 0;
$fp = fopen(time(). '.csv', 'w');
foreach($dizi as $fields) {
    $i++;
    if ($i % 100 == 0) {
        fclose($fp);
        $fp = fopen(time(). '.csv', 'w');
    }
    fputcsv($fp, $fields,';','"');
}
fclose($fp);
```

Notice that if `$dizi` is empty this whole code can be avoid or empty file will be created.